# Mathematica output formatting

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How does Mathematica decide when to round numbers in its output? For example,

giving the input

```
250000.5
```

gives the output

```
2500001
```

While

```
25000.5
```

is indeed printed as

```
25000.5
```

N[] isn't helpful here either, I need to use NumberForm[] to get it to actually print 250000.5 as 250000.5

I'm a Mathematica newbie, and I'm sure its ridiculously easy to control this threshold for when it starts ignoring decimals in its output, but could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default `TraditionalForm` and `StandardForm` output modes Mathematica only shows a certain number of most significant digits. You can use `InputForm` to get the full precision number.

Comment: Thanks alot, thats super helpful :D I'm sat reading up on the precision control as we speak. And I just found the ` operator, can you clairfy onething, if I use ` and `` to specify the number of digits or the numbers of digits in the fractional part, is it ok to just do that on the result, or do i need to specify it on all numbers in the expression?

Comment: Mathematica always just keeps the number of digits which are precise, e.g. 1.0` + 1.0000`==2.0` So when you need full precision in your result you should give your input numbers a sufficient precision from the start.

Answer (score 6):

another option for you to try, you can go to options and change the default `PrintPrecision` from 6 to say 16, and now you will see that it will print what you typed above

[image]

after I changed that to 16 (click on the field itself, and type 16 into the field to replace the 6, and hit return), then

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Nasser is correct that `PrintPrecision` is the right setting.

You have a number of options for its use.  You can set it Globally or for the specific Notebook using the Options Inspector.  You can also use it directly with `Style`:

```
Style[250000.5, PrintPrecision -> 10]
```

> ```
> 250000.5
> ```

You can set it temporarily for one session like this:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision -> 10]
```

Finally you can set it using [Style Sheets](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StylesAndTheInheritanceOfOptionSettings.html) (select cell type `Output`).