# How to display more digits in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, precision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mathematica output formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958531/mathematica-output-formatting)

The number

```
16744.036
```

outputs as

```
16744.
```

which looks strange.

This

```
N[16744.036, 20]
```

is also displayed as

```
16744.
```

I don't know how exactly to name this strangeness. But I need to avoid namely this. I.e. don't hide figures I have entered.

Computer should respect his user, this is the 2nd law of robotics.

Since I entered 3 digits after the point, hence this matters and computer should not omit it. I know it just hides it, but visibility was also my will.

If this general requirement is impossible with Mathematica, then the question is just how to make more digits to be displayed by default?

Comment: Have a look at `NumberForm`.

Comment: But is it possible to make it permanent?

Comment: Answered here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3736/121